# Images to video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am writing as follows for a sequence of images like `image1.png`, `image2.png`, `image3.png` … `image1234.png`. My code for that is:

```
ffmpeg -framerate5 -start number 1 -i ".\Image%4d.png" -pix_fmt yuv420p text.mp4
```

But what pattern is needed for `0001.png`, `0004.png`, `0007.png`, `0010.png`, `0013.png`, `0016.png`, `0019.png`?

Answer (score 2):

## Sequential series

#### 1.png

```
%d.png
```

#### 01.png

```
%02d.png
```

#### 001.png

```
%03d.png
```

#### 0001.png

```
%04d.png
```

#### image0001.png

```
image%04d.png
```

## Non sequential series

If they image inputs are not sequential then use the glob wildcard:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 5 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" output.mp4
```

The glob pattern may not be supported by Windows. In that case rename your images or use `cat`:

```
cat *.png | ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i - output.mp4
```

---

See the [image demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) for more info.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your Reply.But the Code is not working. Can you explain How to add cat for my Images?

Comment: @anil You need to show any errors you get. Can't help without more info. What is your OS?

Comment: Firstly,Thank you for your Reply. My OS is Windows 10

Comment: @anil What error did you get?